# Android - How to load JavaScript Enabled website through AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, android

i am trying to get java script enabled website through AsyncHttpClient

here is my code, please help me as i stuck from morning.

```
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                 client.get("http://www.domain.com/123.php", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1,
                                    String html) {

                                ///do something                                 new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Print All Today Orders").setMessage(html).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();   
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1,
                                    String arg2, Throwable arg3) {
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Print All Today Orders").setMessage("fail").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
                            }
                        });
```

Thanks

Comment: #matt-o please help me

Comment: What Does PHP script 123.php return ? Is it JSON orders ? What do you want make the orders with.